# QuickTime player questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, quicktime

to start assume that we are starting with the following code:
first i include ac_quicktime.js
then call the player like this

```
<div id="qholder">
QT_WriteOBJECT('example.mov' , '320', '240' , '', 'id', 'someid');
</div>
```

note that I gave the player an id by adding : 'id', 'someid' - is that the correct method?

1. how do i programmatically set the src to that of a different video?
2. how do i play the video by clicking an external link?

thanks